# Julia triangular matrix vector BLAS wrapper BLAS.trmv

Tags: julia, blas

I am trying to use the BLAS function dtrmv for triangular matrix vector multiply. According to the docs:

> trmv!(ul, tA, dA, A, b)
>   Returns op(A)*b, where op is determined by tA (N for identity, T for transpose A, and C for conjugate transpose A). Only the ul triangle (U for upper, L for lower) of A is used. dA indicates if A is unit-triangular (the diagonal is assumed to be all ones if U, or non-unit if N). The multiplication occurs in-place on b.

I'm having trouble actually using this. Here is my example:

```
julia> BLAS.trmv('L','N','N',Mchol,Z)
ERROR: MethodError: `trmv` has no method matching trmv(::Char, ::Char, ::Char, ::LowerTriangular{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}, ::Array{Float64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  trmv(::Char, ::Char, ::Char, ::Union{DenseArray{Float64,2},SubArray{Float64,2,A<:DenseArray{T,N},I<:Tuple{Vararg{Union{Colon,Int64,Range{Int64}}}},LD}}, ::Union{DenseArray{Float64,1},SubArray{Float64,1,A<:DenseArray{T,N},I<:Tuple{Vararg{Union{Colon,Int64,Range{Int64}}}},LD}})
  trmv(::Char, ::Char, ::Char, ::Union{DenseArray{Float32,2},SubArray{Float32,2,A<:DenseArray{T,N},I<:Tuple{Vararg{Union{Colon,Int64,Range{Int64}}}},LD}}, ::Union{DenseArray{Float32,1},SubArray{Float32,1,A<:DenseArray{T,N},I<:Tuple{Vararg{Union{Colon,Int64,Range{Int64}}}},LD}})
  trmv(::Char, ::Char, ::Char, ::Union{DenseArray{Complex{Float64},2},SubArray{Complex{Float64},2,A<:DenseArray{T,N},I<:Tuple{Vararg{Union{Colon,Int64,Range{Int64}}}},LD}}, ::Union{DenseArray{Complex{Float64},1},SubArray{Complex{Float64},1,A<:DenseArray{T,N},I<:Tuple{Vararg{Union{Colon,Int64,Range{Int64}}}},LD}})
  ...

julia> typeof(Mchol)
LowerTriangular{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}

julia> typeof(Z)
Array{Float64,1}
```

I'm having trouble interpreting the error. Can anyone help?

EDIT: SOLVED
Mchol as computed by
Mchol=chol(M)'
does not work but MChol computed by 
LAPACK.potrf!('L',Mchol)
works

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Mchol=chol(M)'` but you'll have to extract the buffer first, i.e. `BLAS.trmv('L','N','N',Mchol.data,Z)`. However, I'd recommend that you don't call `trmv` directly. Most often you should use the `Ax_mul_Bx!` family of functions. In this case, the most efficient would probably be to compute

```
Mchol = chol(M)
Ac_mul_B!(Mchol,Z)
```

This will call `BLAS.trmv` when the elements are one of the four BLAS element types but in contrast to `BLAS.trmv` it will still work for e.g. `BigFloat` elements.